# Excel - function "SUM" does not work, but operator "+" does

Tags: excel, string, sum

I have stripped numbers from withing a text column (basically a column of string values from the pdf of a bank statement), by searching for the letter " C " (for "Cleared") and the following space trailing the entry within the text.  This seems to work and generates a column of numbers:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-LEN((LEFT($A3,SEARCH(" C ",$A3)+2)))),SEARCH(" ",D3))
```

Where A3 is the column and row number of the long string of text.

When I attempt to use the "Sum" function over this column,  I get a value of 0; however when I use the operator "+" over the last few cells, the sum of those numbers is returned (there are many numbers in the column, so it is not practical to add each cell).

What am I missing?  Do I need to "cast" the output of the string operator to convert the text to numbers?  If so, why does the operator + work?

Comment: Smells like a format problem. Are your values registered as text or as numeric? Maybe multiply by 1 the result in the formula you've published.

Comment: Add `--` to the front of your formula to turn the text to numbers. Then the sum will work.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Beauty, worked perfectly.  I'm not an excel power user but am pretty adept at it from years of work in finance.  I never knew this way to cast types existed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add -- to the front of your formula to turn the text to numbers. Then the sum will work.